# Why is my SQL ALL operator returning no results?

Tags: t-sql, exists

I am using TSQL and want to select data from a table of `Persons` based on their `StatusID` field, and if all the person's Discharge Dates are prior to today.

A person can have multiple discharge dates.

I am trying to use a sub query with ALL to check if all their discharge dates are prior to today but it isn't working.

What am I doing wrong?

Or is there a better way than SQL ALL?

Here is code sample I tried:

```sql
select distinct  per.PersonNo 
from PersonInfo per, Cases cas
left join Cases cas on per.PersonNo = cas.PersonNo
where (per.StatusID = 3012 
and per.PersonNo = ALL (SELECT cas.PersonNo FROM Cases cas WHERE cas.DischargeDate < getdate() ))
```

I know some of my test data has the right `StatusID` and all their discharge dates are prior to today, and they are not getting selected but they should be.

My query returns no results.

Comment: if your subquery is returning a bunch of dffierent PersonNo values (eg 1, 2, 3, etc), the query will never return any rows. for this query to work, the subquery must return the same PersonNo value for every single row as the outer query's PersonNo value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your join syntax is wrong and also why do you compare `PersonNo`s instead of dates?
Try this:

```
select distinct per.PersonNo
from PersonInfo per left join Cases cas 
on per.PersonNo = cas.PersonNo
where per.StatusID = 3012
and (select max(DischargeDate) from Cases where PersonNo = cas.PersonNo) < cast(getdate() as date)
```

Comment: Well, I thought using ALL and person_no's was the best way.  I didn't think of checking max(dischargeDate) but I tried your solution and it seems to work.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select  distinct per.PersonNo
from    PersonInfo per, Cases cas
        left join Cases cas on per.PersonNo = cas.PersonNo
where   (
            per.StatusID = 3012
            and per.PersonNo = ALL 
            (
                SELECT  cas.PersonNo 
                FROM    Cases cas 
                WHERE   cas.DischargeDate < getdate()
                        and cas.PersonNo = per.PersonNo -- this limits the subquery's PersonNo value to the value that the outer query is expecting
            )
        )
```

Comment: I added the "and cas.PersonNo = per.PersonNo" as you suggested and that seems to work.  Thank you.

Comment: Upon further testing. this did not work for me.  I used the max(DischargeDate)  solution instead suggested by forpas and that worked.

Comment: glad you were able to get a solution here

Answer (score 0):

If you want people without discharge dates equal today (or in the future?) then you can state it using `not exists`:

```
select distinct P.PersonNo
  from PersonInfo as P left outer join
    Cases as C on C.PersonNo = P.PersonNo
    where P.StatusId = 3012 and
      not exists ( select 42 from Cases as IC where IC.PersonNo = P.PersonNo and IC.DischargeDate >= Cast( GetDate( ) as Date ) );
```

Note that different aliases are used for the two references to the `Cases` table and the subquery is correlated with the outer query (`IC.PersonNo = P.PersonNo`).

The `cast` is used to eliminate the time from `GetDate`. That avoids problems with `DischargeDate` if it happens to be a `DateTime` rather than `Date`. Tip: Sharing the DDL for the tables and supplying sample data and desired results helps us help you.

Comment: Why do you select 42?  Otherwise, your solutions makes sense to me and looks similar to the one from forpas which I tried and works.  Thanks for the Cast() tip.   I thought I explained my desired results but will try to better, along with sample data, in the future.

Comment: @BrianS The select list for an `exists` query is a placeholder, i.e. there has to be something there to make the syntax valid, but it has no semantics. You could use a column, `1`, `0`, or an inscrutable `NULL`. I choose to use [The Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker's_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life,_the_Universe,_and_Everything_(42)) to show that I've thought about what to select and made a choice.